# How to Bypass restrictions on the hosts file in windows 8 programmatically?

Tags: java, windows-8, hosts-file

I want to using hosts file in **windows 8** in order to block some websites by redirecting it, I knew that there are some [restrictions](http://www.howtogeek.com/122404/how-to-block-websites-in-windows-8s-hosts-file) put by **Windows Defender** on the hosts file in order to prevent *Malicious Softwares* from missing with it, I want to programmatically (by Java) bypass these restrictions in order to edit the hosts file.

Comment: If you could easily bypass Windows Defender from untrusted software, it wouldn't be doing its job, would it?

Comment: @keshlam no it wouldn't, I'm asking here coz i found that I can bypass it after some steps, so , may be I can do this steps with Java